# Editing rows in a datframe from multiple threads

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading, dataframe

Can someone explain me on how it would be possible to edit rows in a dataframe from multiple threads. Just go give your more context:

**Scenario**
I have a dataframe which holds 2000+ rows. One column in this dataframe holds an `id` that I use to do an external REST API call. The result is then added as a new column to the dataframe (I add the column before i start the processing as it's a known fix `metric` type.)
This basically means for that i need to retrieve the row and do the call for 2000+ entries which take a huge amount of time and I would like to shorten that time by using multiple threads.

**Solution proposal**
One idea I had was to split the dataframe into n-number (equal to the number of threads) of chunks, process them and then finally merge.
Is that approach viable or do you see a better way to solve the problem?

Comment: Your solution is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Python ThreadPoolExecutor:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def task(message_id):
   # send request
   print(message_id)
   return message_id


number_thread=5
ids=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(number_thread)
for id in ids:
    res = executor.submit(task, (id))
```